# Influences of scored/weighted ratings

Tags: estimation, ranking, aggregation, rating

I am experimenting with a scheme for aggregating $N$ scored ratings. The gathered ratings themselves are integers, e.g. a chosen value between $1$ to $5$, and each rating $r_i$ is assigned with a score $s_i$. That is, a data point/record here is a $(rating, score)$ pair. However, $\sum_is_i\neq1$. Naturally, if we sort these $N$ ratings by their scores, we end up with a ranking of them.

Now, I would like to aggregate all the ratings into a single measure, but face a potential problem: for example, given two records $(r_1=5, s_1=0.7)$ and $(r_2=4, s_2=0.8)$, if we simply multiply the rating with its associated score and use the resulting product for aggregation, then we will see a larger influence from $r_1$ than from $r_2$ on the result of aggregation (as $5\times0.7>4\times0.8$) even though $r_2$ scores *considerably higher* than $r_1$.

I wonder what are the appropriate/fair methods/techniques for aggregating in this context. Thanks!

Edit: in response to whuber's comment below, here are some clarifications

- The score for a rating is separately calculated for each rating. We can think of the score as a measure of the 'soundness' of a given rating. As the scores may well be different for different ratings, we can then sort the ratings by their scores in descending order to produce a ranking of ratings.
- One score for one rating, so more precisely, the dataset consists of $N$ number of records each of which is a $(rating, score)$ pair, e.g. $(r_1, s_1)=(5, 0.7)$, $(r_2, s_2)=(4, 0.8)$ as the examples given above.
- By aggregation, I mean combining all given ratings (i.e. the whole dataset) into one single number which is still within the range of individual ratings. In other words, if any individual rating $r_i$ is $1\leq r_i \leq5$, then the aggregated $r^*$ should also be $1\leq r^* \leq5$

Comment: It is unclear what the scores are (parts of the ratings? numbers assigned by the analyst?) or how they "produce a ranking" of ratings.  It seems you have a dataset of integers 1-5, but are the scores assigned to each individual *record* or are there five scores, one for each possible *value*?  What do you mean by "aggregate all the ratings" into a "single measure"?  Will that be one measure for each *record* or one measure for the entire dataset?  Maybe a small example will clarify these issues.

Comment: @whuber, thanks for the comment. I have added some clarifications to the question. please let me know if any other question.